# Who accessed a Hive table or HDFS directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

Is there a way to figure out which user ran a ‘select’ query against a Hive table?  What time it was run?

More generically, which user accessed a HDFS directory?

Answer (score 2):

HDFS has an audit log which will tell you which operations were run by which users. This is an [old doc](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure) that shows how to enable audit logging but should still be relevant. For audit logging at the Hive level though, you'll have to look at some cutting edge tech.

Hortonworks acquired XASecure to implement security level features on top of their platform. Cloudera acquired Gazzang to do the same thing. They have some level of audit logging (and authorizations) for other services like Hive and HBase. They're also adding a lot more security related feature, but I'm not sure of the roadmap though.